# Threading test question

Tags: c#, multithreading

I recently had a interview question in a test that was similar to the below, I do not have very much experience of development using threads can someone please help advise me how to approach this question?:

```
public class StringQueue
{
    private object _lockObject = new object();

    private List<string> _items = new List<string>();

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
            return _items.Count == 0;
    }

    public void Enqueue(string item)
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
            _items.Add(item);
    }

    public string Dequeue()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            string result = _items[0];
            _items.RemoveAt(0);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the following method thread safe with the above implementation and why?

```
public string DequeueOrNull()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        return null;

    return Dequeue();
}
```

Comment: I tagged this C# as it seems like it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me the answer is no.

While isEmpty() procedure locks the object, it is released as soon as the call is returned -
a different thread could potentially call DequeueOrNull() between the call to IsEmpty() and Dequeue() (at which time the object is unlocked), thus removing the only item that existed, making Dequeue() invalid at that time.

A plausible fix would be to put the lock over both statements in DequeueOrNull(), so no other thread could call DeQueue() after the check but before the DeQueue().

Comment: If the fix you wrote was in place, 'put the lock over both statements in DequeueOrNull()", would the locks be necessary in the individual functions?

Comment: @bitbucket: if you take the locks in those out, all thread-safety guarantees will be broken because they're public methods. If they get called in the middle of DequeueOrNull, they won't care if the lock is held and trample over things.

Comment: I guess you would need to lock a different object, otherwise there might be a deadlock. But maybe I'm wrong, I'm not sure what happens when lock statements are nested...

Comment: @Yanir `lock` statements are reentrant. Locking on a different object would not make them thread-safe, it would only bring the problem back!

Answer (score 3):

It is not threadsafe.  At the marked line it is possible that the Dequeue method is called from another thread and thus, the consequent Dequeue return a wrong value:

```
public string DequeueOrNull()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        return null;
///  << it is possible that the Dequeue is called from another thread here.
    return Dequeue();
}
```

The thread safe code would be:

```
public string DequeueOrNull()
{
  lock(_lockObject) {
    if (IsEmpty())
        return null;
    return Dequeue();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because the state of `_items` could potentially change between the thread-safe `IsEmpty()` and the thread-safe `Dequeue()` calls.

Fix it with something like the following, which ensures that `_items` is locked during the whole operation:

```
public string DequeueOrNull()
{
  lock (_lockObject)
  {
    if (IsEmpty())
      return null;

    return Dequeue();
  }
}
```

Note: depending in the [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Semaphore_vs._mutex) of `_lock`, you may wish to avoid double-locking the resource by moving the guts of `IsEmpty()` and `Dequeue` into separate helper functions.

Comment: The `lock` statement calls `Monitor.Enter` which is reentrant.

Comment: @Martinho ah, I see, thank you. When I answered the question, it wasn't tagged C# (and though I assumed it was, I figure interview questions lean toward being language agnostic). I figured the semaphore/mutex concept was worth bringing up, concepts being more important than language-specific implementations.